# Delphi 7 coding to fix a text file

Tags: delphi

I am working with a text file on Delphi 7 and I need to fix errors in each line of the text file, but I am not sure what code to use.

I already have the code to open and display the text file in a rich edit but I don´t know where to go from there.

```
AssignFile(myFile, 'Test.txt'); 
  Reset(myFile);
  while not Eof(myFile) do
  begin
     ReadLn(myFile, text);
     Richedit.lines.add(myFile);
  end;
  CloseFile(myFile);
end;
```

Comment: "fix errors in each line of the text file" What exactly do you mean by that? Do you want to make edits to the text and then save it back again?

Comment: With a `TMemo` you can use `LoadFromFile()` to read the entire file and `SaveToFile()` to save the contents when editing is done.

Comment: `while not eof(myfile) do ReadLineAndFixErrors(myfile);`

Answer (score 3):

You really should not use the 1970's `assignfile/reset` etc calls anymore.

The following code will work:

```
RichEdit1.Lines.LoadFromFile(Filename);
```

When saving the file you do:

```
RichEdit1.Lines.SaveToFile(Filename);
```

If you want to examine the lines of text before injecting (so to spreak) them into the edit control do this:

```
var
  SL: TStringList;
  i: integer;
begin
  SL:= TStringList.Create;
  try
    SL.LoadFromFile(Filename);
    for i:= 0 to SL.Count -1 do begin
      //Fixup is a function that reads the line and returns a corrected line.
      SL[i]:= FixUp(SL[i]);
    end;
    RichEdit1.Lines.Assign(SL);
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

If you want to make sure the file is a pure text file, use a `TMemo` instead.
It works the same as above with `TRichEdit`.